# KeyError when placing codes inside a function

Tags: python, pandas

Some data:

```
ID      InBedTime           OutBedTime      DateInBed   DateOutBed  CountInBedDate  CountOutBedDate
CFL200  15/05/2018 20:58    16/05/2018 0:17 15/05/2018  16/05/2018  1   2
CFL200  16/05/2018 0:27     16/05/2018 4:05 16/05/2018  16/05/2018  2   2
CFL200  16/05/2018 22:38    17/05/2018 1:27 16/05/2018  17/05/2018  2   1
CFL200  17/05/2018 23:14    18/05/2018 4:41 17/05/2018  18/05/2018  1   1
CFL200  19/05/2018 0:12     19/05/2018 4:32 19/05/2018  19/05/2018  2   1
CFL200  19/05/2018 21:01    20/05/2018 3:42 19/05/2018  20/05/2018  2   1
CFL200  20/05/2018 23:00    21/05/2018 4:08 20/05/2018  21/05/2018  1   1
CFL200  22/05/2018 0:08     22/05/2018 4:24 22/05/2018  22/05/2018  2   1
CFL200  22/05/2018 20:53    23/05/2018 0:50 22/05/2018  23/05/2018  2   1
CFL203  16/05/2018 2:48     16/05/2018 6:32 16/05/2018  16/05/2018  2   1
CFL203  16/05/2018 21:03    17/05/2018 6:15 16/05/2018  17/05/2018  2   1
CFL203  18/05/2018 0:02     18/05/2018 5:52 18/05/2018  18/05/2018  2   1
CFL203  18/05/2018 21:35    19/05/2018 0:48 18/05/2018  19/05/2018  2   2
CFL203  19/05/2018 0:58     19/05/2018 5:35 19/05/2018  19/05/2018  2   2
CFL203  19/05/2018 22:58    20/05/2018 5:59 19/05/2018  20/05/2018  2   1
CFL203  20/05/2018 20:51    21/05/2018 1:36 20/05/2018  21/05/2018  1   1
CFL203  21/05/2018 21:44    22/05/2018 4:43 21/05/2018  22/05/2018  1   1
```

When I run these codes, no error

```
L1 = s1.groupby(['ID', 'DateOutBed'])['OutBedTime'].transform('last')
s1['last_time'] = L1.mask(s1[['ID', 'DateOutBed']].duplicated())
OutBedTimeFinal = s1['last_time']
```

When I put those inside if-else:

```
def f(row):
 if row['CountInBedDate'] == 1 and row['CountOutBedDate'] == 2:   
    SleepDate = row['DateInBed']
    InBedTimeFinal = row['InBedTime']

    L1 = s1.groupby(['ID', 'DateOutBed'])['OutBedTime'].transform('last')
    s1['last_time'] = L1.mask(s1[['ID', 'DateOutBed']].duplicated())
    OutBedTimeFinal = row['last_time']
 else:
    SleepDate = np.nan
    InBedTimeFinal = np.nan
    OutBedTimeFinal = np.nan

 return SleepDate, InBedTimeFinal, OutBedTimeFinal
```

The first time I run this

```
s1[['SleepDate', 'InBedTimeFinal', 'OutBedTimeFinal']] = pd.DataFrame(s1.apply(f, axis=1).tolist(), s1.index)
```

There is:

```
KeyError: 'last_time'
```

I run it again, no error. I tried to create 'last_time' column before running apply() but it does not work. What should I do to not have to run it twice? Thanks.

Update more codes:

```
def f(row):
 if row['CountInBedDate'] == 1 and row['CountOutBedDate'] == 1:
    SleepDate = row['DateInBed']
    InBedTimeFinal = row['InBedTime']
    OutBedTimeFinal = row['OutBedTime']

 elif row['CountInBedDate'] == 2 and row['CountOutBedDate'] == 1:
    if row['DateInBed'] == row['DateOutBed']:
           SleepDate = row['DateInBed'] - dt.timedelta(days=1)
           InBedTimeFinal = row['InBedTime']
    else:
        SleepDate = row['DateInBed'] 
        InBedTimeFinal = row['InBedTime'] 

    OutBedTimeFinal = row['OutBedTime']

 elif row['CountInBedDate'] == 1 and row['CountOutBedDate'] == 2:
    SleepDate = row['DateInBed']
    InBedTimeFinal = row['InBedTime']

    L1 = s1.groupby(['ID', 'DateOutBed'])['OutBedTime'].transform('last')
    s1['last_time'] = L1.mask(s1[['ID', 'DateOutBed']].duplicated())
    OutBedTimeFinal = row['last_time']

 elif row['CountInBedDate'] ==2 and row['CountOutBedDate'] == 2:
    if row['DateInBed'] != row['DateOutBed']:
        SleepDate = row['DateInBed']
        InBedTimeFinal = row['InBedTime']

        L1 = s1.groupby(['ID', 'DateOutBed'])['OutBedTime'].transform('last')
        s1['last_time'] = L1.mask(s1[['ID', 'DateOutBed']].duplicated())
        OutBedTimeFinal = row['last_time']
    else:
        SleepDate = np.nan
        InBedTimeFinal = np.nan
        OutBedTimeFinal = np.nan
 else:
    SleepDate = np.nan
    InBedTimeFinal = np.nan
    OutBedTimeFinal = np.nan

 return SleepDate, InBedTimeFinal, OutBedTimeFinal
```

Created the column before running the funciton:

```
s1['last_time'] = np.nan
```

the output was: 
[image]

The expected output when running the function twice
[image]

Comment: Could you please add some sample data to the post, so one can reproduce your issue?

Comment: @Roy2012: I have added some data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    s1['last_time'] = L1.mask(s1[['ID', 'DateOutBed']].duplicated())
```

This creates the 'last time' column for your entire dataframe.
But the row you already fed in to your function does not have the column yet.

It works on the second run because you will already have the column from the previous run(even if it fails because it fails after creating the column!).

Put this 2 line outside your function and it will work:

```
L1 = df.groupby(['ID', 'DateOutBed'])['OutBedTime'].transform('last')
s1['last_time'] = L1.mask(df[['ID', 'DateOutBed']].duplicated())
```

This will create the required columns BEFORE youre asking for them.
Also your function will be easier to read(for me) this way.

df.apply applies your function to a row, not to your entire dataframe.
I think its a good idea in general to keep only row-related actions in your row-related function and create the columns that your function will query before you call your function.

[It looks like this for me, but i'm not sure what output is desired...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mi8f5.png)

Comment: @Ference Lippai: but I have multiple if-else with lines similar to these two lines. If I put them outside of the function, I have to create multiple columns 'last_time1' 'last_time2'... Do you have another solution? Thanks.

Comment: @Ference Lippai: as I mentioned before, I did try to create column 'last_time' before running the function but it does not work. The results will not be correct.

Comment: Please show your current results and the expected results.

Comment: I used this to create a new column: s1['last_time'] = np.nan before running the function. The results were not correct. I cannot add the output here so will add to the question

Comment: Your output is not what I want, I have added the expected output to the question. Please have a look.

Comment: Your output is only different in the first row as far as i can see, right? You used s1['last_time'] = np.nan? because that will cause your first row to be nan..(but not for the others)

Comment: I think so. Also, I did not recognize that I have the two lines in different if-else are identical now. I am not really sure if it is a good idea to move those two lines outside but I will try and see how it goes.

Comment: As i said, that 2 line belongs to outside of the function. And you only need to run them once(as opposing to several times in your function).
The np.nan one that you used is not needed/ not right for this scenario.
Please find the original screenshot in my response for reference. NOTE that i used DIFFERENT dataframe thats why my first 2 results are NAN.
I really hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue, as you suspected, is with the line:

```
OutBedTimeFinal = row['last_time']
```

You're adding `last_time` column to the dataframe a couple of lines earlier, but by then row already exists, and it doesn't have the `last_time` column.

As to what should you do: it's probably best to do the entire calculation in a vectorized manner.

Comment: Could you please show me how to do that? I am very new to python. Thanks.

Comment: It would be great if you could add the expected output to the question, and maybe explain the logic.